# Удалить из файла строки, содержащиеся в листе

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        var files = "inputData.txt";
        list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(files));

        var result = list.Distinct(new PartialComparer()).ToList();

        foreach (var v in result)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("finalResult.txt", v + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Я записываю уникальные значения. При этом хочу, чтобы из исходного файла удалялись строки, которые я взял. Если исходный файл имеет вид: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3. То после удаления там должно остаться: 1,2,3(т.е. удалять только один экземпляр строки). Как можно реализовать такое удаление?

```
class PartialComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public string GetComparablePart(string s)
    {
        return s.Split('@')[1];
    }
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return GetComparablePart(x).Equals(GetComparablePart(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return GetComparablePart(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Перезаписать файл содержимым, где были бы только нужные (оставшиеся) значения. Используйте `File.WriteAllLines()` вместо `File.AppendAllText()`.

Comment: @BlackWitcher я имел ввиду, что finalResult мне нужен "сейчас", а из inputData я через какое-то время опять буду брать уникальные значения и записывать в finalResult.

Comment: А что мешает сейчас так делать? Берете `inputData.txt`, читаете в `List`, добавляете в него содержимое `finalResult.txt`, применяете `Distinct`, сохраняете перезаписывая `finalResult.txt`. При необходимости - повторить. Соль и сахар по вкусу :-)

Comment: @BlackWitcher изначально в inputData.txt есть повторяющиеся строки, мне нужно, чтобы он удалил только 1 вариант такой строки. т.е. после первой итерации от списка (1,2,3,4,1,2) должно остаться (1,2) в inputData.txt

Comment: Понял. А `PartialComparer()` как у вас реализован?

Comment: @BlackWitcher добавил код реализации в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я могу предложить велосипед

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        var files = "inputData.txt";
        list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(files));

        var result = list.Distinct().ToList();

        if (list == null && list.Count==0)
            return;
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++ )
        {                
            if(i<result.Count && list.Contains(result[i]))
            {
                indexes.Add(list.IndexOf(result[i]));
            }
        }
        int delIndex = 0;
        foreach (int i in indexes)
        {            
            list.RemoveAt(i + delIndex);
            delIndex--;
        }
        //list - с удаленными значениями
        foreach (var v in result)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("finalResult.txt", v + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @cruim Я запускаю этот код со списком (1.2.3.4.1.2.2)  у меня  в list остается 1.2.2 как и должно быть по условию!

Comment: Все верно. Добавил только File.Delete("inputData.txt");
            foreach (var v in list)
            {
                File.AppendAllText("inputData.txt", v + "\n");
            }

Answer (score 1):

Попробую без велосипедов, но с LINQ:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    var files = "inputData.txt";
    list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(files));

    //Заменим вашу строку:
    //var result = list.Distinct(new PartialComparer()).ToList();
    //на
    var result = list.GroupBy(f => f).Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);

    foreach (var v in result)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("finalResult.txt", v + "\n");
    }
}
```

Здесь как раз получится, что из списка подобного (1,2,3,4,1,2) в `inputdata.txt` останется (1,2).

**UPDATE:**

Вот так вот работает на любой последовательности элементов, удаляя повторяющиеся элементы 1 раз и игнорируя не повторяющиеся:

```
        string s = "1,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,8,2,5,2,2,1"; //Вывод: 1,1,2,2,2,5
        List<string> FileList = new List<string>();
        FileList = s.Split(',').ToList();
        FileList.Sort();
        List<string> Collected = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < FileList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (FileList[i] == FileList[i + 1])
            {
                Collected.Add(FileList[i]);
            }
        }

        //Вывод простенько, без затей:
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", Collected));
```

Единственное, из-за сортировки нарушается порядок элементов (в итоговом списке они отсортированы).

> Я записываю уникальные значения. При этом хочу, чтобы из исходного файла удалялись строки, которые я взял. Если исходный файл имеет вид: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3. То после удаления там должно остаться: 1,2,3(т.е. удалять только один экземпляр строки).

Именно это и делает код после update - из исходного списка забирает один экземпляр строки, при условии, что строка встречается в списке более одного раза.

Если и это работает не так, как вам хотелось бы, то большая просьба в вопросе как-то более подробно (так, что бы нам понятно было), растолковать, что же вы хотите получить на выходе :)

Comment: Не совсем корректно получается. при входных данных (1,2,3,4,1,2,2), на выходе получится (1,2), а не (1,2,2)

Comment: @ cruim велосипед на этой выборке едет!

Comment: @YuryBakharev специально еще раз проверил, если  исходном файле более двух одинаковых строк, то он все равно их перепишет в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: Обновил ответ, дополнив его.